# sbt-native-packager include different application.conf depending on parameter

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have a simple `sbt` application that uses `typesafe-config` library and is build using `sbt-native-packager`.

I build it using following command:

```
sbt universal:packageBin
```

Within the `src` directory I have following hierarchy:

```
main/resources/application.conf
test/resources/application.conf
staging/resources/application.conf
```

And my archive always ends up containing only the `main` version of `application.conf`

I'm looking for a easy way to include specific `application.conf` file based on for example java property passed during project build, but I'm unable to find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the `mappings` facility, which allows you to add/remove files from the base layout? See [Change-Remove Top Level Directory In Output](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/universal.html#change-remove-top-level-directory-in-output) in the official docs.